# Dynamic Power BI OData data source location

Tags: powerbi

We have a web application which is installed on customer sites.

They get to choose the name of the web server and the port that it runs on.

The web application exposes some data via an OData endpoint.

The web application also serves some template Power BI files (.pbit)

At the moment, when the customers run the pbit files for the first time, the data refresh fails and they have to relink their data source.

We use data source referencing and store the location of the endpoint in a parameters table but it's still a pain for the customers to have to change this value, and, since we (the web application) know the endpoint URL, we'd like to be able to update the pbit file with the appropriate setting.

Ideally we'd like an API to be able to manipulate the pbit file, or maybe to be able to supply parameters to Power BI desktop, or even load the pbit file (which is a .zip file as I'm sure you know!), and alter the appropriate part within it.

Has anyone actually managed to do programatically or dynamically change a data source URI without needing manual intervention?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Query Parameters feature for this (more details in the link below).  Note as of the July 2016 update, the source for parameters can now be another Query.

So I would build that "parameter allowed values" query by pointing at an Azure SQL instance or some other web-visible source that helps them choose the right value.

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/deep-dive-into-query-parameters-and-power-bi-templates/

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-july-feature-summary/

Comment: As I said, we've tried this approach but it still involves asking the customer to edit values inside their PBIX/PBIT files to link the the OData endpoint (url) of their installation. We already know this when when serve them the file and we want to be able to push this customer-specific parameter into the file some way

Comment: This is probably the closest you can get to that at this point.  What did you use for the "parameter allowed values" query?

Comment: I didn't use a list of allowed values as they are infinite (customers can name their servers anything they want) - so, instead I used a parameters table which the customer has to edit the table cell and this cell is referenced in the building of the OData endpoint URI